# Uploading a file and getting the uploaded percentage in MVC and JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a file upload feature in MVC4 with a jquery progress bar.

I have done the file uploading part. What I need to do next is find uploaded data size during uploading and use that value to populate the progress bar.

How can I get uploaded data size during uploading a file?

I am not expecting a whole block of code for the complete file upload. What I need is a reference or a code block, on how to get the uploaded data size. I have used c# for my application.

Comment: I just found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following link. You need to use the XMLHttpRequest object to periodically check the progress and update the progress bar values. I have not yet done the coding for this, but will update once its done.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest

Thanks,